# Getting Data Structures from PHP to JS, then proceed with GET

Tags: javascript, php

I'm a bit overwhelmed with how PHP and JS share variables. I have a button on my page which when clicked needs to save data to a config file on the server.

The data will be read on pageload via PHP, the result is a array-list with objects.
I transfer these objects to JS with the following trick:

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'var scenariolistjs = ' . json_encode($scenariolist, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . ';';
echo 'var anz_scenariosjs = ' . json_encode($anz_szenarios, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . ';';
echo 'var anz_slavesjs = ' . json_encode($anz_slaves, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . ';';
echo '</script>';
```

When i print these variables in the console.log, the objects are correctly transferred. The problem now is that on the button click i need to call a php file on the server to save the data to files. so i transfer the variables again, but this time via get:

```
$(function() {
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() { 

console.log('You clicked button with ID:' + this.id);
console.log(scenariolistjs[this.id[4]].slavelist);

$.get('/savexml.php', { 
pscen: scenariolistjs[this.id[4]].name, 
pslaves: scenariolistjs[this.id[4]].slavelist, 
});

});
});
```

My savexml.php then receives the variables:

```
<?php

$scen = $_GET['pscen'];
$slaves = $_GET['pslaves'];


file_put_contents('upload/test.xml',$slaves);

?>
```

But file_put_contents just prints "ArrayArrayArrayArray".

My Problem is that i don't know in which namespace the variables are available.

1. Could it be that i can access the variables in savexml.php without parsing them because the calling .php already had them defined?
2. Or are they only viable for the .php there are defined in?
3. Is there an easier way to transfer the data from the button click to the file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to print GET values in your  savexml.php, are you getting expected values there?

Comment: `this.id` seems an input id but what is the `this.id[4]`?

Comment: the id is a string, and the 5. character is a unique number in that string so i can differentiate the buttons.